# Accessibility service cannot simulate touch on soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard, accessibilityservice

I am developing an app for remote control within the organization. The working concept is similar to Team Viewer and Anydesk, using Media Projection and Accessibility Service.

What I have successfully accomplished so far are:

1. I can access devices through a remote server (which I developed myself) via a web interface and send X, Y coordinate values to the controllable device.
2. The client device can receive X, Y coordinates and perform touch commands on the screen through AccessibilityNodeInfo's performAction Click.
   The current issue I am facing is that I am unable to simulate touches on the soft keyboard using X, Y coordinates, unlike how it works for other parts of the screen.

What I aim to achieve is the ability to touch any point on the screen using the X, Y coordinates received from the web server.

I have been researching additional topics like IME and Input Connection for several days, but I'm not certain if they will help solve the issue. Could you please provide me with some guidance or suggestions?

Comment: I've fixed the issue! It's because I was focusing on the wrong node.